# how to run/call a function after N day/hour

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to run/call a function after `N` day or hour, this time is changeable and I cannot set a `CRON` job.

for example:

```
one(1)
one(2)
one(24)

function one($hour)
 {

    call two(); function after $hour

 }


function two()
 {

    //do something

 }
```

Is there any library to do this?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server where this will be running?

Comment: How time-critical is this? Does it matter if it's out by a few minutes? Is it for a website? How busy is that website? Do you have database storage?

Comment: - Does it matter if it's out by a few minutes?
yes, The exact time is important.

- Is it for a website?
yes. 

- How busy is that website?
no problem. because We have a strong server.

- Do you have database storage?
yes. mysql.

Comment: You *can* write a (PHP-)script which is doing a `while-true-loop`, sleep a second (or more), checking the time and doing stuff. This works if you execute your script via shell, without execution timelimit. Normally the execution time is limited, exactly because of errorneous scripts which are endless.

*BUT*, I would not recommand this approach!

Comment: It is regrettable you don't mention what you want to use this for. That really limits what we can suggest.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian did any of the provided solution work for you?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian, Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Add set_time_limit(0) in the top of your PHP script to override the php.ini max execution time limit.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

# Define your frequency
$days = 1; 
$hours = 1; 
$minutes = 1; 
$seconds = 1; 

# Convert inputs into seconds
$frequencySeconds = (
    ($days * 24 * 60 * 60)  +
    ($hours * 60 * 60)      +
    ($minutes * 60)         +
    ($seconds) 
);


$startTime = microtime(1);

while(1) {

    # Get current timestamp
    $timeNow = microtime(1);

    # Find out how much time elapsed
    $elapsedTime = $timeNow-$startTime;

    # Check that time has surpassed frequency
    if( $elapsedTime >= $frequencySeconds) {

        /* 
            insert your main code here 
        */

        # Update new start time
        $startTime += $frequencySeconds;

    }
}
?>
```

However, bear in mind, the script might end due to browser HTTP timeout and/or Apache server max execution time defined in the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Please you a job queue, that is more efficient than cron jobs. I already implement this to a PHP codeigniter project and already running in production.

Here is the links for the implementation

https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/working-with-php-and-beanstalkd.

https://github.com/davidpersson/beanstalk